# Woocommerce one page check out - hide add to cart message

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried all kinds of methods to try and get rid of the scrolling for after adding an item to the cart... It will scroll all the way to the top of the page.. I don't care if the message stays but how can I stop the scroll?? I have a snippet plugin that has given me the ability to override woocommerce hooks so something to override this should work, but is there a way to override a scroll?

This is an override to woocommerce from OPC ( one page checkout plugin ) I would like to refrain from going into the code to the plugin as it causes my site to crash anytime I comment out or add code in plugins.. So I have a snippet plugin that helps with that.

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout', function(){
    if ( response_messages.length > 0 ) {
        $( '#opc-messages' ).prepend( response_messages );

        if ( ! $( '#opc-messages' ).visible() ){
            $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
                scrollTop: ( $( '#opc-messages' ).offset().top - 150 )
            }, 500 );
        }

        response_messages = ''
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a functionality of your theme and not by WooCommerce itself. Check this [js](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js) file for add to cart button in the WooCommerse GitHub Repo.

Check the theme have an option to disable this feature in the admin panel. If no such option are there you can change the code in the theme itself or you can create a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. You can kind of hack your way into a solution by over-riding the animation in your own javascript. In the OPC js they are using an `updated_checkout` event to run the scroll animation. You can bind a handler function to that same event to cancel the animation.

```
$(document.body).on('updated_checkout', () => {
  $('html, body').stop(true, false);
});
```

It's not an ideal fix by any means, but it does seem to do the trick. What would be great is if the plugin developer wrote their JS so it was extendable from within a theme :)